# 404 error - File or directory not found. This is happening with certain pages when using Chrome Web Browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been hired into a company that uses ASP.NET for all of their external and internal sites. I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET.

I'm currently working on a external site that runs perfectly in Internet Explorer.

When using the site on chrome, I have certain pages that give me the **404 - File or directory not found.**

What can I do to help prevent this error code from showing up when using this site the chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I understand that your site is a legacy site that is compatible with the IE browser but it is not working properly with modern browsers.

The 404 error information generally informs us that something is not found but if the site works fine in the IE browser then it could be possible that the issue is something else. In that case, this is too little information to predict the cause of the issue.

You may need to provide detailed information about which exact piece of code has the issue. Which version of the Asp.Net project and which kind of project(Web application, web API, etc.) it is. You may need to modify your code or project to make it work with modern browsers including Google Chrome.

At present, if you don't want to make any changes in your code then you could try to use the [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) in the MS Edge browser to load your legacy site.

You could configure the IE mode manually or using the group policy.

To quickly check it, Launch the Edge browser. Paste `edge://settings/defaultBrowser` in the address bar and press the Enter key. Add your page to the **Internet Explorer mode pages**. Visit your site, it should load properly in the IE mode in the Edge browser.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback! Very much needed and I will be more detailed next time.

Comment: You could let us know if you need further suggestions on this issue. I will be happy to assist you further. If the above answer helps you with your question and you don't have further questions. You could consider accepting the answer to this question or you could post your own answer. Thanks for your understanding.